# 15.10, Getting some 404 errors when I apt-get update

Tags: apt, updates, 15.10, ppa

Specifically, it's for some PPAs and not the system in general. The URLs are, as far as I can tell, correct. I only use `sudo apt-get update`, and tried the `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` solution suggested in one of the suggested threads. The specific error is:

`Err http://ppa.launchpad.net wily/main i386 Packages

  404  Not Found`

Of course, this is just one of four. The complete set is at the bottom of this post. Like I said, the URL is alright as far as I know, as it follows the same format as other updates which didn't 404. So, any idea as to the solution for this?

The full list:

`Err http://ppa.launchpad.net wily/main amd64 Packages

  404  Not Found`

`Err http://ppa.launchpad.net wily/main i386 Packages

  404  Not Found`

`W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/caffeine-developers/ppa/ubuntu/dists/wily/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found`

`W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/caffeine-developers/ppa/ubuntu/dists/wily/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found`

Comment: You could try the answer I posted here.
http://askubuntu.com/questions/750344/error-in-sudo-apt-get-update-on-ubuntu-15-10/750356#750356

Comment: @RifazNahiyan, sorry, but I'm not so sure that worked. Unless there is a specific server you can recommend to enter in manually, my only option was to go from the US server to the main server, and that doesn't seem to have helped.

Answer (score 0):

The ["Caffeine Developers" PPA](https://launchpad.net/~caffeine-developers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) does not have packages for Wily, as you can see because "Wily" does not appear in the "Published in" drop-down list. This is probably because version 2.8.3 of `caffeine` is in the official Wily repositories, rendering this PPA useless.