# Error in sudo apt-get update on ubuntu 15.10

Tags: ppa

when i do sudo apt-get update i get these errors;

```
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net wily/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/restricted Translation-en
```

Please could someone help out

Comment: Please provide the entire output (yes, this means *all* the lines).

Answer (score 1):

I think the Ubuntu Servers may be having a problem. To get a workaround, you can use a mirror instead of Ubuntu's Main servers for updating/installing software.

To do that:

1. Open up Dash (by pressing the super key).
2. Search for "update" and click on *Software & Updates*. You should get a window that looks like [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8r339w484u6f4i3/Software-updates.png?dl=0).
3. Choose a different download server by clicking the drop-down menu next to *Download from:*
4. Click *Close*. And your software repositories should be updated. This is equivalent to the command: `apt-get update`

You should now be able to install latest versions of the softwares available in your repository from the command line, or the GUI.